# How to wipe a RAID 5?

Tags: raid, raid5

I want to wipe all data from a raid5 but continue using it afterwards. A single pass of overwriting would be enough. How can I do this?

Would this wipe only the data, or also the raid superblock?

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/md0p1
```

Answer (score 1):

That would wipe it all. This might be a little faster:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/[DESTROY ME] bs=1M
```

If you want to zap it with randomly generated data please see,
https://superuser.com/questions/792427/creating-a-large-file-of-random-bytes-quickly